# How many ways are there to partition a triangle into 4 triangles? What about 5 triangles?

Tags: combinatorics

"Let $\triangle ABC$ be a fixed triangle. Denote $f(n)$ to be the number of ways to partition $\triangle ABC$ into exactly $n$ triangles. (Two partitions are considered the same if they are "topologically equivalent" to each other.)"

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1907401_number_of_triangle_partitions

The first few values of f(n) are listed in the link above. Is there an easy way to find f(4) or f(5)? Is there a pattern?

Comment: The go-to source when you have a couple terms of a sequence and want to know if it has been studied is to go to www.oeis.com and enter those terms and see if the sequences that come up seem like similar problems to yours.

Comment: You will have your answer there : https://oeis.org/A056814